# Java Stream API - Best way to transform a list: map or forEach?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list, `myListToParse`, where I want to filter the elements and apply a method on each element, and add the result in another list, `myFinalList`.

With the `Stream` API (added in Java 8), I noticed that I can do it in 2 different ways. I would like to know the more efficient way between them and understand why one way is better than the other one.

Method 1:

```
myFinalList = new ArrayList<>();
myListToParse.stream()
        .filter(elt -> elt != null)
        .forEach(elt -> myFinalList.add(doSomething(elt)));
```

Method 2:

```
myFinalList = myListToParse.stream()
        .filter(elt -> elt != null)
        .map(elt -> doSomething(elt))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm open for any suggestion about a third way.

Comment: The second one. A proper function should have no side effects, in your first implementation you are modifying the external world.

Comment: just a matter of style, but `elt -> elt != null` can be replaced with `Objects::nonNull`

Comment: You can use the parallelStream `myFinalList = myListToParse.parallelStream().filter(elt -> elt != null).map(elt -> doSomething(elt)).collect(Collectors.toList());` to boost performance

Comment: @the8472 Even better would be to make sure there are no null values in the collection in the first place, and use `Optional<T>` instead in combination with `flatMap`.

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski, not quite. For something as trivial as this, the work needed to setup the parallelstream under the hood will make using this construct mute.

Comment: @I.K. yes, that's true, not everytime parallelization is a good choice. But if your data is quite big, you can think about it.

Comment: Note that you can write `.map(this::doSomething)` assuming that `doSomething` is a non-static method.  If it's static you can replace `this` with the class name.

Comment: there's a third way (using [toArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method)) - will add below for the sake of completeness, but the method 2 is preferrable

Comment: why not `.filter().collect()`??

Comment: With Java 17 `map(elt -> doSomething(elt)).collect(Collectors.toList());` can be `map(elt -> doSomething(elt)).toList()); ` The Java 17 version has the added benefit of returning an immutable list.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Don't worry about any performance differences, they're going to be minimal in this case normally.

Method 2 is preferable because

1. it doesn't require mutating a collection that exists outside the lambda expression.
2. it's more readable because the different steps that are performed in the collection pipeline are written sequentially: first a filter operation, then a map operation, then collecting the result (for more info on the benefits of collection pipelines, see Martin Fowler's [excellent article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/).)
3. you can easily change the way values are collected by replacing the `Collector` that is used.  In some cases you may need to write your own `Collector`, but then the benefit is that you can easily reuse that.

Answer (score 59):

I agree with the existing answers that the second form is better because it does not have any side effects and is easier to parallelise (just use a parallel stream).

Performance wise, it appears they are equivalent until you start using parallel streams. In that case, **map** will perform really much better. See below the [micro benchmark](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/master/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO28319064.java) results:

```
Benchmark                         Mode  Samples    Score   Error  Units
SO28319064.forEach                avgt      100  187.310 ± 1.768  ms/op
SO28319064.map                    avgt      100  189.180 ± 1.692  ms/op
SO28319064.mapWithParallelStream  avgt      100   55,577 ± 0,782  ms/op
```

You can't boost the first example in the same manner because **forEach** is a terminal method - it returns void - so you are forced to use a stateful lambda. But [that is really a bad idea if you are using parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#stateful_lambda_expressions).

Finally note that your second snippet can be written in a sligthly more concise way with method references and static imports:

```
myFinalList = myListToParse.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(this::doSomething)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: About performance, in your case "map" really wins over "forEach" if you use parallelStreams. My benchmaks in milliseconds: SO28319064.forEach: 187,310 ± 1,768  ms/op -- SO28319064.map: 189,180 ± 1,692  ms/op --SO28319064.mapParallelStream: 55,577 ± 0,782  ms/op

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone, it's up to assylias, but to my opinion your edit contradicts the original author's intent. If you want to add your own answer, it's better to add it instead of editing the existing one so much. Also now the link to the microbenchmark is not relevant to the results.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use the [`collectIf()`](https://eclipse.dev/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/RichIterable.html#collectIf(org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate,org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function)) method to filter and transform at the same time.

```java
myFinalList = myListToParse.collectIf(
    Objects::nonNull,
    elt -> doSomething(elt));
```

It evaluates eagerly and should be a bit faster than using a `Stream`.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: While this seems correct and may be good advice, this does not answer the question asked, which is about transformation/map.

Comment: @PhilippeCloutier I edited my answer to use the doSomething() method that appears in the original question, to clarify that collectIf() does transform/map in addition to filtering.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I submitted an edit to clarify that this addresses the OP's specific problem.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main benefits of using streams is that it gives the ability to process data in a declarative way, that is, using a functional style of programming. It also gives multi-threading capability for free meaning there is no need to write any extra multi-threaded code to make your stream concurrent.

Assuming the reason you are exploring this style of programming is that you want to exploit these benefits then your first code sample is potentially not functional since the `foreach` method is classed as being terminal (meaning that it can produce side-effects).

The second way is preferred from functional programming point of view since the map function can accept stateless lambda functions. More explicitly, the lambda passed to the map function should be

1. Non-interfering, meaning that the function should not alter the source of the stream if it is non-concurrent (e.g. `ArrayList`).
2. Stateless to avoid unexpected results when doing parallel processing (caused by thread scheduling differences).

Another benefit with the second approach is if the stream is parallel and the collector is concurrent and unordered then these characteristics can provide useful hints to the reduction operation to do the collecting concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second way.

When you use the first way, if you decide to use a parallel stream to improve performance, you'll have no control over the order in which the elements will be added to the output list by `forEach`.

When you use `toList`, the Streams API will preserve the order even if you use a parallel stream.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct advice: he could use `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach` if he wanted to use a parallel stream but still preserve the order.  But as the documentation for `forEach` states, preserving the encounter order sacrifices the benefit of parallelism.  I suspect that is also the case with `toList` then.

Comment: OK.  According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html `the collect method is designed to perform the most common stream operations that have side effects in a parallel-safe manner. Operations like forEach and peek ... if you use one of these operations with a parallel stream, then the Java runtime may invoke the lambda expression that you specified as its parameter concurrently from multiple threads. ` So it carefully has some things atomic and some not. Weird.  Assuming that is the case, option 1, if made parallel, might have contention issues...

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option - using `stream().toArray()` - see comments under [why didn't stream have a toList method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method). It turns out to be slower than forEach() or collect(), and less expressive. It might be optimised in later JDK builds, so adding it here just in case.

assuming `List<String>`

```
    myFinalList = Arrays.asList(
            myListToParse.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(this::doSomething)
                    .toArray(String[]::new)
    );
```

with a micro-micro benchmark, 1M entries, 20% nulls and simple transform in doSomething()

```
private LongSummaryStatistics benchmark(final String testName, final Runnable methodToTest, int samples) {
    long[] timing = new long[samples];
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        methodToTest.run();
        timing[i] = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }
    final LongSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(timing).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.println(testName + ": " + stats);
    return stats;
}
```

the results are

parallel:

```
toArray: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=3721, min=321, average=372,100000, max=535}
forEach: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=3502, min=249, average=350,200000, max=389}
collect: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=3325, min=265, average=332,500000, max=368}
```

sequential:

```
toArray: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=5493, min=517, average=549,300000, max=569}
forEach: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=5316, min=427, average=531,600000, max=571}
collect: LongSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=5380, min=444, average=538,000000, max=557}
```

parallel without nulls and filter (so the stream is `SIZED`):
toArrays has the best performance in such case, and `.forEach()` fails with "indexOutOfBounds" on the recepient ArrayList, had to replace with `.forEachOrdered()`

```
toArray: LongSummaryStatistics{count=100, sum=75566, min=707, average=755,660000, max=1107}
forEach: LongSummaryStatistics{count=100, sum=115802, min=992, average=1158,020000, max=1254}
collect: LongSummaryStatistics{count=100, sum=88415, min=732, average=884,150000, max=1014}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Method 3.

I always prefer to keep logic separate.

```
Predicate<Long> greaterThan100 = new Predicate<Long>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Long currentParameter) {
        return currentParameter > 100;
    }
};
        
List<Long> sourceLongList = Arrays.asList(1L, 10L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 133L, 333L);
List<Long> resultList = sourceLongList.parallelStream().filter(greaterThan100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If using 3rd Pary Libaries is ok [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) defines Lazy extended collections with this functionality built in. For example we could simply write

ListX myListToParse;

ListX myFinalList = myListToParse.filter(elt -> elt != null)
                                 .map(elt -> doSomething(elt));

myFinalList is not evaluated until first access (and there after the materialized list is cached and reused).

[Disclosure I am the lead developer of cyclops-react]