# Why didn't Stream have a toList() method?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

When using the Java 8 streams, it's quite common to take a list, create a stream from it, do the business and convert it back. Something like:

```
 Stream.of(-2,1,2,-5)
        .filter(n -> n > 0)
        .map(n -> n * n)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why there is no short-cut/convenient method for the '`.collect(Collectors.toList())`' part? On Stream interface, there is method for converting the results to array called `toArray()`, why the `toList()` is missing?

IMHO, converting the result to list is more common than to array. I can live with that, but it is quite annoying to call this ugliness.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would ask the opposite question: why `toArray()` instead of `collect(toArray())`. API explosion is something the JDK tends to fend off as much as possible. I expect there to be good justification for `toArray()`.

Comment: Why stop on `toList`? Lets also add `toStack` `toSet` `toMap`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik right, thx, I eddited the answer

Comment: ...but I don't think this should be closed as "Primarily opinion-based". I'm sure the Java language architects active on this site can give an authoritative answer. In fact, I suspect they have already done so and my Google-foo is letting me down.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't have any numbers, but in my opinion the list is the far most used collection out there. The reason is the convenience (and Scala has it :])

Comment: The relevant number here is that of those who would, in the alternate reality where `toList()` existed, complain about the lack of `toSet()`, `toMap()`, and all other `toX()`s combined. I suspect that the number is very much the same, and this way we have one less method to scroll down through while vading through the vast domains of the `Stream` API.

Comment: Here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-May/009798.html

Comment: with a static import you can reduce it to `collect(toList())`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Your observation about the slippery slope did indeed factor into the decision.  The reason arrays are special is: they *are* special.  1) They're built into the language (and therefore have more claim for inclusion), and 2) excluding them would have given up on some big parallelism opportunities (our implementation of toArray exploits characteristics like SUBSIZED; in the best case, toArray allocates one big array and writes the elements concurrently into place, with zero copying or locking.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz Yes, the key difference between `collect(toArray())` and `toArray()` is in the amount of coupling. BTW this would suggest that `asList(stream.toArray())` is something to consider instead of `stream.collect(toList())` when parallel performance is critical.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Looks like `asList(stream.toArray())` is slower than `stream.collect(toList())`, at least on JDK 1.8.0.20. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319064/java-8-best-way-to-transform-a-list-map-or-foreach) for some benchmarks

Comment: @harshtuna You haven't done enough warmup. Also, don't include warmup in your timing. I've benchmarked this using JMH and without doing any extra work with filter and map (that just dilutes the differences).  With the size of 2 million I see 8.5 ns per element for `toArray()` and 20.3 ns for `collect(toList())` in the sequential case. For parallel I see modest speedup for `toArray()` and a *slowdown* for `collect(toList())` (that's because I don't do any other work).

Comment: @harshtuna: that’s a different case than Brian Goetz described as a filtered stream has *no* `SIZED` characteristics. Therefore, `toArray` has to predict and merge similar to `collect` in this case, hence does not exploit the big advantage that it has for streams with a predictable size.

Comment: @Holger, fair point, Splitterator is still a bit mystery for me

Comment: What I miss much more is a `toIterable()`. With it I could feed anything I'd want, plus could just iterate over it. (Ok, I can do `(Iterable<T>)(stream::iterator)`, but that's ugly as well.) Or a `Stream<T>` could just implement `Iterable<T>`, then all would be fine...

Comment: @BrianGoetz "excluding them would have given up on some big parallelism opportunities" Not if it would have been implemented under `Collectors` as well.

Comment: @glglgl No. Try implementing it; you'll find the Collector API insufficient to pull this off with no copying.  It would have complicated the Collector API substantially to track sufficient information to do this as efficiently as is done inside of Stream.

Comment: Arrays.asList is fairly effective.

Comment: Cause java does not care about developers and lambda is just akward to work with if compared to c#. Not just toList but also the whole structure is off. C# lambdas follow always simple SQL syntax in defined order `FROM, WHERE, GROUP, SELECT / PROJECTION`. Java lambda it depends on what you want to do. Instead of `stream.filter(...).any()` we do `stream.any(...)`. It saves some minor typing but makes the stream / query not reusable. Sometimes you want first to check any and then do some other stuff with same filter. I find java lambda as a big of missconcept as old java Date namespace.

Answer (score 13):

Recently I wrote a small library called [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) which extends Java streams and provides this exact method among many other features:

```
StreamEx.of(-2,1,2,-5)
    .filter(n -> n > 0)
    .map(n -> n * n)
    .toList();
```

Also toSet(), toCollection(Supplier), joining(), groupingBy() and other shortcut methods are available there.

Answer (score 13):

Java 16 introduced [Stream.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()):

```
Stream.of(-2,1,2,-5)
    .filter(n -> n > 0)
    .map(n -> n * n)
    .toList();
```

The new method is slightly different from the existing `collect(toList())`: it returns an unmodifiable list.

Answer (score 6):

As for the "why", I believe there are quite a lot of arguments in the comments. However, I agree with you in that it's quite annoying to not have a `toList()` method. Same happens with a `toIterable()` method.

So I'll show you a trick that lets you use these two methods anyway. Fortunately, Java is very flexible and allows you to do all kinds of interesting stuff. About 10 years ago, I read [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue108.html), which describes a witty trick to "plug" methods to any given interface. The trick consists of using a proxy to adapt the interface that doesn't have the methods you want. Over the years, I've found that it has all adapter pattern's pros, whereas it lacks all of its cons. That's what I call a big deal.

Here's a sample code, just to show the idea:

```
public class Streams {

    public interface EnhancedStream<T>
        extends Stream<T> {

        List<T> toList();

        Iterable<T> toIterable();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> EnhancedStream<T> enhance(Stream<T> stream) {

        return (EnhancedStream<T>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            EnhancedStream.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[] {EnhancedStream.class}, 
            (proxy, method, args) -> {

            if ("toList".equals(method.getName())) {

                return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

            } else if ("toIterable".equals(method.getName())) {

                return (Iterable<T>) stream::iterator;

            } else {
                // invoke method on the actual stream
                return method.invoke(stream, args);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream<Integer> stream1 = Stream.of(-2, 1, 2, -5).
            filter(n -> n > 0).map(n -> n * n);
        List<Integer> list = Streams.enhance(stream1).toList();
        System.out.println(list); // [1, 4]

        Stream<Integer> stream2 = Stream.of(-2, 1, 2, -5).
            filter(n -> n > 0).map(n -> n * n);
        Iterable<Integer> iterable = Streams.enhance(stream2).toIterable();
        iterable.forEach(System.out::println); // 1
                                               // 4
    }
}
```

The idea is to use an `EnhancedStream` interface that extends Java's `Stream` interface by defining the methods you want to add. Then, a dynamic proxy implements this extended interface by delegating original `Stream` methods to the actual stream being adapted, while it just provides an inline implementation to the new methods (the ones not defined in `Stream`).

This proxy is available by means of a static method that transparently performs all proxying stuff.

Please note that I'm not stating that this is a final solution. Instead, it's just an example that can be highly improved, i.e. for every method of `Stream` that returns another `Stream`, you could return a proxy for that one too. This would allow `EnhancedStream`s to be chained (you'd need to redefine these methods in the `EnhancedStream` interface, so that they return an `EnhancedStream` covariant return type). Besides, proper exception handling is missing, as well as more robust code to decide whether to delegate the execution of methods to the original stream or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple helper class that makes this easier:

```
public class Li {
    public static <T> List<T> st(final Stream<T> stream) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
List<String> lowered = Li.st(Stream.of("HELLO", "WORLD").map(String::toLowerCase));
```

Comment: If you're going to do this you might as well go with Collectors.toList() just for the sake of comprehensibility.