# Effective and shortest way to convert array A[] to ArrayList<B>

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 classes

A:

```
  public class A {
    private int intValue;
    private String stringValue;

    public A(int intValue, String stringValue) {
      this.intValue = intValue;
      this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    int getIntValue() {
      return intValue;
    }

    String getStringValue() {
      return stringValue;
    }
  }
```

and B:

```
  public class B {
    private int intValue;
    private String stringValue;

    B(int intValue, String stringValue) {
      this.intValue = intValue;
      this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    int getIntValue() {
      return intValue;
    }

    String getStringValue() {
      return stringValue;
    }
  }
```

and some pretty big array of A objects.

And I want to convert `A[]` to `ArrayList<B>` effectively. I know several ways to do this:

```
final A[] array = {new A(1, "1"), new A(2, "2")/*...*/};

// 1 - old-school
final List<B> list0 = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (A a : array) {
  list0.add(new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue()));
}

// 2 - pretty mush same as 1
final List<B> list1 = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(a -> list1.add(new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue())));

// 3 - lambda-style
final List<B> list2 = Arrays.stream(array).map(a -> new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());

// 4 - lambda-style with custom Collector
final List<B> list3 = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(a -> new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue()))
    .collect(Collector.of((Supplier<List<B>>)() -> new ArrayList(array.length), List::add, (left, right) -> {
      left.addAll(right);
      return left;
    }));
```

AFAIK 1 is most efficient. But with java 8 features it's possible to make it shorter. 2 is pretty much the same as 1, but with `foreach` loop replaced by stream `foreach`. Not sure about it's effectiveness. 3 is the shortest way, but default `Collectors.toList()` collector uses default `ArrayList::new` constructor, which means that array in `ArrayList` will be resized at least once if we have pretty big initial array. So it's not so efficient. And 4, as I understood it (never used this way though) is pretty much the same as 3, but with single memory allocation for array in `ArrayList`. But it looks ugly.

So, my question is. Am I right about these 4 ways and their effectiveness? Is there any other short and effective way to do this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, `Arrays.asList()` converts only `A[]` to `List<A>`, that's not what I want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For a list that can be appended to or removed from, `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #4 could be written a bit more shortly:

```
final List<B> list4 = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(a -> new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue()))
    .collect(toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(array.length)));
```

You could also extract the mapping in a separate method:

```
final List<B> list4 = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(SomeClass::mapA2B)
    .collect(toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(array.length)));    

private static B mapA2B(A a) {
  return new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue());
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's actually pretty short and human-readable :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the most efficient solution, you may consider

```
List<B> list=Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(a -> new B(a.getIntValue(), a.getStringValue()))
    .parallel().toArray(B[]::new));
```

Unlike, `collect`, which works with the `Collector` abstraction, `toArray` is an intrinsic operation of the `Stream`. Since the stream returned by `Arrays.asList` has a known size, the implementation will create one target array and write into distinct regions of that array when processing in parallel. In contrast, `collect` will create multiple lists, process them in parallel and merge them afterwards which is unsuitable for an operation as simple as this one.

Even for the single threaded use, it’s likely to perform better as it is just filling an array (“working on the raw metal”) and creating a lightweight `List` view of it afterwards.

This idea is a direct consequence of [this comment made by Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method#comment45848538_28782165)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I can't use `parallel` stream. And for regular `stream()` that will work same, AFAIK. And `Arrays.asList()` returns not quite `ArrayList` I need :)

Comment: Right, if your requirement is to get exactly an `ArrayList` instead of just a `List` (i.e really need the ability to change its size later on), that won’t help. And for sequential streams the impact is not so big if you are already using a custom `Supplier` returning an `ArrayList` with the right capacity.