# Collect Objects in Array

Tags: java, java-8

I want to filter the `CC` addresses of the array and want to collect it to the same array,

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
String[] ccAddress = emails.split(";");
ccAddress = Arrays.stream(ccAddress)
                  .filter(adr -> "".equals(adr) == false)
                  .collect(Collectors.toArray);// ?????
```

My question is, 'Is there any direct way to collect filtered elements to the array in Java8' ?

*NOTE : I know I can simply collect them to List and write `list.toArray()` to get array but that is not my question.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you checked [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)?

You can use `Stream.toArray` method:

```
String[] ccAddress = emails.split(";");
ccAddress = Arrays.stream(ccAddress)
        .filter(addr -> !addr.isEmpty())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Did you checked documentation? Yes, but my overcomplicated mind brought me down to the Collector and never thought it can have `toArray` to collect in to array. Thanks. :)

Comment: @TAsk you may always introduce your own `Collector` in the same manner as `toArray`: https://gist.github.com/ginz/62144450dbc6cf34261a

Comment: @TAsk: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method#comment45848538_28782165) helps understanding why `toArray` is a stream method instead of a collector…