# Why toList() is not there directly on Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I understand that Java 8 Stream provides `.collect` method to convert a Stream to any collection / data Structure of our choice, and it is very generic in nature. Understand that Stream might be originated from non-collection object / resouce. But from usage perspective, it is pretty natural to convert Stream to List / Set.

Stream already provides `toArray()` method to convert to array, so why not `toList()` and `toSet()`?

Comment: [Retrieving a List from Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830313/retrieving-a-list-from-a-java-util-stream-stream-in-java8) is closely related.

Comment: It's a compromise between pollution of the interface and ease of use. They chose not to pollute the interface more. Adding toList() would ask for a toSet() method as well, then a toMap(), etc. etc., ultimetely repeating many methods of Collectors, and making the Stream interface more complex and "polluted" with many collecting methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method

Comment: The `toArray()` method could easily be implemented as `Collector` as well. I guess, it's added directly to the Stream interface for efficiency reasons: if your Stream is sized, you can take an advantage of it preallocating the array of exact size. This is currently impossible for collectors: they are unable to get the size of the stream in advance. There's a [request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072840) to fix this, though no work seems to be done yet in this direction.

Comment: @TagirValeev I have one related question about `.toArray`. Why does it return `Object[]` , not `T[]` ?

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta: because due to Java generics limitations you cannot create an array of unknown type. There's `toArray` with function parameter which returns the array of any type (for example, `toArray(String[]::new)`).

Comment: @Tagir Brian Goetz additionally argued that arrays are a native special case in Java so they deserve their method; the same argument does not propagate to all the Collections Framework types.

Answer (score 6):

Because you wouldn't know what the `List` implementation would be like:

- would it be mutable?
- would you be able to change its size?
- etc etc.

In fact, [even `Collectors.toList()` makes no guarantee](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).

As such, providing a generic `.toList()` method would fit some usages for some people, but it would never be able to fit all usages for all people. And of course, the same applies to `Collectors.toSet()`.

Arrays are not a problem however: you know what you can do with them.

Comment: Why would this argument apply against having a `toList` `Stream` method and not against having a `toList()` Collector to be used in the Stream's `collect` method?

Comment: @Eran well, another reason is that depending on the `Stream` implementation you may have lists returned with different characteristics, unless the contract of the method is well defined. As such the decision makes sense imho.