# Java 8 : Convert dates using stream

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert dates dynamically. I tried this method but it is returning void.

How to make it an array of `LocalDate` objects?

```
String[] datesStrings = {"2015-03-04", "2014-02-01", "2012-03-15"};
LocalDate[] dates = Stream.of(datesStrings)
                          .forEach(a -> LocalDate.parse(a)); // This returns void so I
                                                             // can not assign it.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Using `forEach` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28319064/1743880) for this task: you would need to mutate an external variable.

What you want is to map each date as a String to its `LocalDate` equivalent. Hence you want the `map` operation:

```
LocalDate[] dates = Stream.of(datesStrings)
                          .map(LocalDate::parse)
                          .toArray(LocalDate[]::new);
```