# optimizing java 8 stream operations

Tags: java, optimization, java-stream

So I was trying to optimize my code as much as possible. The following code used to run on 5,something seconds, however I managed to reduce it to about 1,4 seconds, however it's still not enough. What can I do to optimize this code even more? (Maybe I should mention that the times I talked about happen when the aux Map ends up with 170080 keys).

```
    public List<String> getProdutosMaisCompradosQuantidade(int filial, int X){
    Map<String, ProdutoFilial> aux;

    if(filial==0) {
        aux = new HashMap<>(ValoresFixos.CATALOGO_PRODUTOS_TAMANHO_INICIAL);
        filiais.stream()
               .forEach( (f) -> {
                    Map<String, ProdutoFilial> aux2 = f.getMapProdutosDadosFilialSemEncapsulamento();
                    aux2.forEach((k,t) -> {
                            if(t.getQuantidade()>0){
                                if(aux.containsKey(k)) aux.get(k).atualizarValores(t);
                                else aux.put(k,t);
                            }
                    });
                });
    }
    else aux = filiais.get(filial-1).getMapProdutosDadosFilialSemEncapsulamento();

    List<String> list = 
       aux
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(new ComparadorProdutoQuantidade())
       .map(e -> e.getKey()+"\n     |   o Quantidade: "+e.getValue().getQuantidade()+"; Comprado por "+e.getValue().getNumeroCompradores()+" Clientes Distintos")
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if(X>list.size()) X = list.size();
    list.subList(X, list.size()).clear();

    return list;

}
```

All the methods I use here are almost O(1) complexity and the comparator isn't too taxing either so that shouldn't be the problem, is there something I may not know that could help me optimize this stream operations? Maybe the entrySet I use can be avoided...? Because it's probably the most expensive operation here...

EDIT1: Maybe I should explain the idea behind this method. It's main purpose is to order the map aux and return a list with the keys ordered (the keys are also modified but that's not the main intention)

Comment: You are talking about "ordering" keys, but `aux` is a HashMap and those do not have a defined order. Have you thought about parallelizing everything using e.g. a `parallelStream()`instead of a `stream()`? If you do don't forget synchronization of `aux`.

Comment: O(1) only means it doesn't scale with input size. It can take a constant year for everything for example. And for optimizing a few seconds, these constant time differences make a hell of a difference (and sometimes O(something larger than 1) is even faster in practice - typically arrays vs linked object structures). PS: it would be very helpful if you translated your code, understanding how valores and produtos relate to each other makes it a lot easier to understand your algorithm or what's it about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to replace the `forEach` statements with `map` and `collect`, as described in [Java 8 - Best way to transform a list: map or foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319064/java-8-best-way-to-transform-a-list-map-or-foreach)

Then you could try if using a parallel stream improves your performance.

It is probably possible to replace your statement which creates the `aux` map with the Stream API (using [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and/or [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)). This is considered cleaner than using `forEach`, which uses stateful operations.

There are already quite many question for how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=groupingBy+[java-stream]
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=toMap+[java-stream]

If you need a quicker solution (with less changes), you could try to replace the `Map` with a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and use a parallel stream. You can use [its merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to make your computation parallelizable.

Comment: I tried to use Collectors instead of forEach but I couldnt find a way to do it the way I pretend so I tried using a parallelSetream insted of a stream and it was just amazing, used it on the rest of my code and it made everything more then a couple of seconds faster like if it was nothing, I'm really surprised and amazed. However I wanna make sure I dont mess up, I use concurrentHashMaps when I can and use the reserved word synchronized on methods that really can't be called concurrently, but Is there anything else I should be catious about?

Comment: And also, is there any danger in using parallelStreams with ArrayLists or HashSets? As long as I just want to access data and not modify it

Comment: @sharp_c-tudent: When you use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, it should be ok if you use atomic operations like merge. As for the limitations of parallel streams, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream

Comment: @sharp_c-tudent: Actually, to put it more clearly, you should prefer atomic operations like `putIfAbsent` or `merge` and not use `sychronized` with a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @sharp_c-tudent:If you only read from Collections concurrently without modifying them, it should be no problem

Comment: Thanks and for the forEach situation i found that the compute metod on the maps could be used instead wich also helped a lot