# Fetch List of object from another list using java 8

Tags: java

```
List<Customer> customers = findAllCustomer();   

public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private State state;

    //getter and setter
```

I have below approached using jdk 7

```
List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

for (Customer customer : customers) {
    states.add(customer.getState());
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing using jdk 8?

Comment: Also, the original code is not terrible and still works perfectly fine with JDK8+  ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stream the contents, map to get the state and collect it as a List.

```
customers.stream()
    .map(Customer::getState)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need an `ArrayList` as the resultant list

```
customers.stream()
    .map(Customer::getState)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

customers
    .stream()
    .map(Customer::getState)
    .forEach(states::add);
```

Comment: "List<State> states = new ArrayList<>(); " why are you declaring the arraylist if you are using java 8? You should never do it like this. Always use collect and Collectors. This is bad.

Comment: @ABHISHEKHONEY this is not bad. That was just another way.

Comment: Kindly refer this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319064/java-8-best-way-to-transform-a-list-map-or-foreach

Comment: @ABHISHEKHONEY they said that " that was preferable" not bad :) because it doesn't require mutating a collection and it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda and forEach

```
customers.forEach(p -> {
        states.add(p.getState())  
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<State> states = customers.stream()
                              .map(Customer::getState)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Additionally you can wrap this issue to the **static method**:

```
public static List<State> getCustomerStates(List<Customer> customers) {
   return customers.stream()
                   .map(Customer::getState)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

...or to the **function**:

```
private static final Function<List<Customer>, List<State>> getCustomerStates =
        customers -> customers.stream()
                              .map(Customer::getState)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your **function** declaration: Replace the lambda operator after `getCustomerStates` with assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to mentions that if the `state` is actually a `List<state>` (`states`)

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private List<State> states;//Important note: I changed State to a List<State> here

//getter and setter
```

It will be a little bit tricky to get a List of `states` here

```
List<State> states = customers.stream()
    .map(Customer::getStates)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)//null check
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If state is already a List, then `states.add` wouldn't have worked. The OP should have used `addAll`

Comment: @user7 Sorry but I don't get your comment? My answer mentions another case OP might need. And I didn't say anything about `add` and `addAll`?

Comment: If it is another case, then it is fine. But in OP `state` cannot be a List. So, this doesn't answer the **current** question

Comment: @user7 did you read my answer or not? I specific said `Worth to mentions that if...` and I actually did define a `List<State> states` in the first code part? Is it not enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187310/discussion-between-dang-nguyen-and-user7).