# Multiple streams filter or forEach if-else

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I have a small list which I have to separate into 2 lists based the value of an element. I am looking at 2 ways to do this -

1. Either iterate the list twice using filters.

```
List<String> sublist1 = list.stream().filter(condition1).collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
List<String> sublist2 = list.stream().filter(condition2).collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

2. Use a forEach in streams to assign values

```
List<String> sublist1 = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> sublist2 = new LinkedList<>();
list.stream().forEach(element -> {
    if(condition1) sublist1.add(element);
    else if (condition2) sublist2.add(element);
})
```

I wanted to know which way is better and more efficient to implement this?

Comment: Of ofcourse when you iterate just once rather than twice. For a specific case, one can also benchmark how significantly.

Comment: Looks like you're "partitioning your list", see https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split#use-java8-to-partition-the-list for single-iteration options with Java8.

Comment: In addition to iterating through everything twice, the first example presumably involves copying the entire resultant collection at the end. (if you think about how an immutable collector must work, it is likely to mutably accrue elements, before finally creating a new immutable list from the mutable one as the last step)

Comment: By the way, you should almost always prefer ArrayList to LinkedList. You could initialize them both to the size of the original list, which is likely to be larger than you need, but it's better than potentially resizing multiple times to reach the necessary capacity

Comment: `list.stream().forEach()` in the second case seems to be redundant, can be replaced with `list.forEach` or an equivalent loop `for(E element: list)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have specifically two conditions resulting in two sub-lists and they are *alternate* that is only one of the two conditions may be true, you could use OR in `filter` or `Predicate.or` and then use `Collectors.partitioningBy` by either condition:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<String>> sublistMap = list
        .stream()
        .filter(condition1.or(condition2))
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(condition1, Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()));

List<String> sublist1 = sublistMap.get(Boolean.TRUE); // condition1
List<String> sublist2 = sublistMap.get(Boolean.FALSE); // condition2
```

Test

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "cc", "ddd", "aaaa", "vvv", "oo");
Predicate<String> condition1 = (s) -> s.contains("o");
Predicate<String> condition2 = (s) -> s.contains("a");

System.out.println(sublist1);
System.out.println(sublist2);
```

Output:

```
[oo]
[a, aaaa]
```

Comment: My usecase was more of a String compare of value in one of the attribute in the class object. So `partitioningBy` won't work in my case.

Comment: Do you mean that both `condition1` and `condition2` may be true at the same time?

Comment: While this is a cool trick, I believe it's neither faster nor more readable than any of the approaches from the original question.

Comment: @apangin, FYI: [Java 8: best way to transform a list: map or forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319064/java-8-best-way-to-transform-a-list-map-or-foreach)